# Can't set a field to be unique in a Meteor Collection

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I'm trying to set one field to be unique using simple schema. But no matter what I do it's not working. Here's how I set it up :

```
let schema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Committee name',
    max: 200
  },
  shortName: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Short name',
    max: 10,
    index: true,
    sparse: true,
    unique: true,
    autoValue: (com) => {
      if (com.shortName) {
        return com.shortName.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  },
});
```

I even tried to reset meteor. If I add a duplicate value, it won't add the record but won't even give any errors when validating.

Comment: Are you using insert update or upsert?

Comment: Yep. To add the item I use `insert` But before that I use the validate method to get the error : `Collection.simpleSchema().namedContext('insertForm').validate(values)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in validation for unique fields in simple schema. You have to use custom simple schema validation as mentioned in the [official docs](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema#asynchronous-custom-validation-on-the-client).

```
username: {
  type: String,
  regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/,
  unique: true,
  custom() {
    if (Meteor.isClient && this.isSet) {
      Meteor.call("accountsIsUsernameAvailable", this.value, (error, result) => {
        if (!result) {
          this.validationContext.addValidationErrors([{
            name: "username",
            type: "notUnique"
          }]);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This will give invoke custom validation using validation context.

Note: This will be asynchronous as it has to query the database on server side to check whether the field contains unique data item or not.